# thenReturn() method is throwing compilation error while mocking

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito, junit5

while I tried to use thenReturn() method it's giving a compilation error 
"The method thenReturn(Dimension) in the type OngoingStubbing is not applicable for the arguments (int)"
with the below code

```
@Test
public void LetsMockListClass() {
    List listmocked=mock(List.class);
    when(listmocked.getSize()).thenReturn(2);
    assertEquals(2, listmocked.getSize());
}
```

Comment: What `List` class are you talking about? Judging from the error message the `getSize()` method seems to return a `Dimension` object instead of an `Integer`.

Comment: It’s recommended to always show imports in your Java code since a lot of potential errors hide in wrong imports.

Comment: i will append imports.

Comment: in this code, i tried to mock List.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely not a Mockito problem, but an issue of a wrong import statement:

- `java.awt.List` has a `getSize()` method returning an object of type `java.awt.Dimension`.
- `java.util.List` has a `size()` method returning an `int`.

A version with a correct import statement may look like this:

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import java.util.List;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class ListMockTest {

    @Test
    public void letsMockListClass() {
        List<?> listMock = mock(List.class);
        when(listMock.size()).thenReturn(2);
        assertEquals(2, listMock.size());
    }
}
```